# JAVA FX css editor warning on VSCODE

Tags: css, javafx, visual-studio-code

I am using javafx 15 with java 11.0.8 with visual studio code.

I think vscode does not recognize javafx css. It shows warnings such as:
"Also define the standard property 'background-image' for compatibilitycss(vendorPrefix)"
for property fx-background-image and it will do the same for all fx- prefixes.

It is as if vscode does not know about javafx css and relies on "web rules".

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, I found that you can choose to ignore the warning messages in the settings of vscode.

`1. Press  : Ctrl + ,`

`2. Search : CSS > Lint: Vendor Prefix`

`3. Select : ignore`

Comment: Ok but this will disable the autocomplete feature right?

Comment: Not sure man, my autocomplete is not even working for fx- before.

Comment: I recommend adding this as a project setting instead of in your global user settings. If you don't have a `.vscode` folder you can create it and inside of it a `settings.json` file. In there, you can add `"css.lint.vendorPrefix": "ignore"` for your JavaFX project.